# Get Sensor event.values.length() (without waiting for onSensorChanged())

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I need to find All the sensor's `event.values.length()` programmatically. So what I'm doing is, registering all the sensor to get the every sensor's `event.values.length()`. For most of the sensors, `onSensorChanged()` was getting invoked in short time. But for some other sensors, the device need to be in motion. Then only `onSensorChanged()` will be triggered.

[I found this official doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) But is there any way to find `event.values.length()` programmatically.

Comment: You can convert the documentation you listed to a set of static final int constants that hold the respective value, for example `static final int ACCELEROMETER_DIMENSION = 3;`

Comment: yeah I've done like that now, but what if they added new sensors in feature ? Again we need to add another fields for that sensors and more validations too. If we can get that values length dynamically it would like be more robust.

Comment: Why do you need to listen for every sensor type? Usually you register for the specific sensor you want to use.

Comment: It's a requirement. Need to get all the Sensor's name and output values count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to find Sensors `event.values.length`. Not sure it's a right way but it's works.

```
 Method[] methodList = Sensor.class.getDeclaredMethods();
 int m_count = methodList.length;
 for (int j = 0; j < m_count; j++) {
     Method method = methodList[j];

     if (!method.getName().equals("getMaxLengthValuesArray")) {
        continue;
     }

     method.setAccessible(true);
     try {
          int values_length = (Integer) method.invoke(mSensor, mSensor, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
          Log.e(TAG,"value length is "+values_length);
          break;
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```